# Html 5 canvas getElementById() returns null/undefined

Tags: html, html5-canvas

here's the code:

HTML:

```
<body onload="initializeMap()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1"></div>
    <canvas id="control" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2">Does Not Support Canvas Element</canvas>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('control');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function draw(){
        context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
        context.fillText("x", 248, 43);
    }
</script>
```

the draw function is called after initialization of the google map so the DOM should have already loaded by then, correct? What might have I done incorrectly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DOM has already been loaded when the `draw`-function is called, that is correct.

But the `var canvas = document.getElementById('control');`-line is evaluated before that, because it is not in the `draw`-function. It is executed immediately in the `<head>` of the document BEFORE the elements have been rendered.

I would suggest you change your init function to something like that

```
var canvas,context;
function initializeMap() {
   canvas = document.getElementById('control');
   context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `javascript` is loaded prior to your `body` then canvas will be `undefined` because the browser hasn't loaded/rendered it yet.

Comment: It's on the <head> tag but the function is called . Shouldn't it work normally? any examples?

Comment: I don't see a function, I set a variable setter `var canvas = doucment.get...('control');`  There is no document when the browser runs javascript in the head.

Comment: the javascript is declared on the <head> but the function draw() is called after the document is loaded which would be fine.